# Convert images to pdf using img2pdf package in python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert images in folder named `Final` to one pdf
This is my try to achieve the task

```
import os
import img2pdf

with open("Stickers.pdf","wb") as f:
    #print(os.listdir("./Final"))
    f.write(img2pdf.convert([x for x in os.listdir("./Final") if x.endswith(".png")]))
```

But I got an error message like that (any idea how to fix that)

```
 File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\demo.py", line 5, in <module>
    f.write(img2pdf.convert([x for x in os.listdir("./Final") if x.endswith(".png")]))
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\img2pdf.py", line 2263, in convert
    ) in read_images(
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\img2pdf.py", line 1444, in read_images
    im = BytesIO(rawdata)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: i just tried same code and worked. my python is 3.8.2 and img2pdf 0.4.3. what about yours?

Comment: Thanks a lot. My python version `Python 3.9.7` and img2pdf is 0.4.3 (the same as yours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is cryptic largely because `img2pdf` bends over backwards to be so versatile about what you can pass to the `convert` function: a file name, an open file object, raw image data, multiples of any of those, or a list. If it tries opening a file and fails, it then assumes the input is raw image data (as bytes) and attempts to process it that way, in which case you get the `TypeError` that you see.

The reason it can't open the files correctly is that `os.listdir` returns only the file names themselves, not their full path, and those image files aren't in your current working directory. That is, you're trying to open `example.png`, not `./Final/example.png`.

You can fix this by manually adding the folder name to each file name:

```
import os
import img2pdf

with open("Stickers.pdf","wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert([f'./Final/{x}' for x in os.listdir("./Final") if x.endswith(".png")]))
```

You could also use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). It often makes dealing with paths [easier](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/) (and more easily platform-independent) than messing about with `os`. `Path` objects are smarter than plain strings, and automatically know about their enclosing folder in this case.

All of Python's builtins (like `open`) will accept a `Path` object anywhere where you could also use a string representing a path, but unfortunately `img2pdf` does not follow suit, so you'll still have to convert them back to strings. I still think this is a little nicer, personally, but your mileage may vary:

```
from pathlib import Path
import img2pdf

with open("Stickers.pdf","wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert([str(path) for path in Path('./Final').glob('*.png')]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

Instead of

```
[x for x in os.listdir("./Final") if x.endswith(".png")]
```

Try:

```
[open(x,'rb').read() for x in os.listdir("./Final") if x.endswith(".png")]
```

Comment: Interesting. Have you tested this? According to the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/) (and, as I recall, to my own testing, though I'm not currently at a computer), `convert` is supposed to work perfectly well with string file names.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tested that but I got `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Sample.png'` although the file is already there